# Check 2D list for containing only 2 specific values

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I need to check a 2d array to ensure that it only contains 2 specific characters.

Assume I have this in a 2d array stored in a list called (data):

```
**%****%%%***
%***%*%%****%
****%%%$*****
```

I need to validate that the array only contains ('*', '%')
If it contains any other value such as ('$'), it needs to return false and print a statement to the user.

I tried using forall but could not get it to work with a 2d array.

Also in Python 3x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [ '**%****%%%***', '%***%*%%****%', '****%%%$*****' ]
result = all( (len(x) == x.count('*') + x.count('%')) for x in  data)
```

I have represented the 2D array here as list of strings.

If you change the representation to list of lists, it will still work (as `count` function is available for both `str` and `list`).

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to change it to list of lists, but cannot get it to function correctly. Other than running this before reading the data from a file. I don't want to have to read it from the file twice.